Is a statement considered false or nonsense (invalid), if it consists of a verb applied to a false statement?
Consider the statement:

[1] It's funny that Amy is jumping

If Amy isn't jumping, is this sentence considered false or nonsense (invalid)?
The following statement is clearly nonsense (invalid):

[2] The 3-headed horse is flying

Because no 3-headed horse exists.
But I'm not sure about the first statement?
Another statement is:

[3] Amy is laughing results in Peter is smiling

Is this statement false or nonsense (invalid), if Amy isn't smiling?

sentence 1 - invalid. It says amy is jumping, you say she isn't. As for sentence 3, the idea is fine, but there is some kind of subject/ verb agreement issue. It should read 'Amy's laughter results in Peter smiling' (awkward but valid) or how about 'when Amy laughs, Peter smiles.' ? This is a conditional statement -- it doesn't matter if Amy is laughing right now, or if she ever laughed before. It only says what will happen when she does laugh.

Do these good questions in logic apply to English alone?
If Amy isn't smiling, it may still be true that "Amy laughing results in Peter smiling."

This is probably one for Philosophy SE. It's about how we categorize different statements, not the English language in itself.

yes and no. Logically, it doesn't matter if Amy has ever laughed. The statement holds. In real life, in language, we would assume there was some kind of wavy, empirical evidence to this fact -- ie very often, in the past, when Amy laughed, peter smiled. In logic, it would have to be true every single time.

I could see it both ways. Maybe that's silly. esp w the grammatical error.

This is one for Philosophy SE, since it's an active topic in analytic philosophy.

There's nothing grammatically wrong with saying that a three-headed horse is flying. It might be part of a fantasy story in which a three-headed, winged horse exists.

[1] is grammatical. If untrue, the statement violates the Gricean maxim of quality. // [2] is grammatical but either nonsense or in the fiction domain. [3] is ungrammatical; perhaps 'Amy's laughing results in Peter['s] smiling'. But your question about [3] remains unclear: do you mean 'if Peter isn't smiling'? It could be an over-generalisation, an error, a lie (again, the Gricean maxim of quality is to varying degrees violated).

How is this a question specifically about the English language? Can't you have similar nonsense in any language? This is about philosophy of language, and [language.se] is the proper place to ask.

I’m voting to close this question because this is about philosophy of language, not about English.

@ness Why can't Amy is laughing be a subject? I could write It results in Peter is smiling that Amy is laughing. In that case it refers to Amy is laughing. What's the difference between an invalid and a false statement?

Amy is the subject, laughing is the verb. 'Amy is laughing' is not a subject. You cannot write " It results in Peter is smiling that Amy is laughing." It does not make sense and it is really unclear which is the result. (You can't say 'it' first without referencing what 'it' is beforehand.) There are a few other critical serious grammar errors, that I can't quite pinpoint, as well. I was using invalid and false interchangeably.

Just to tangentially point out that in logic, every false statement is invalid (logically invalid), and that every statement that is not well-formed is not well-defined.


Amy is laughing results in Peter is smiling.

That is ungrammatical and nonsensical, as the word is often used by native speakers.  Unless you define "nonsense" we can only opine on how the word is used in the wild.
[Amy is laughing] is not a valid subject of a verb. Nor is [Peter is smiling] a valid object of the preposition in.
You can make a content-clause:

[That Amy is laughing] makes Peter smile.

And if you're constructing a new symbolic language using English as a base, but breaking English grammatical rules, the question isn't on-topic for this site.

Why is Amy is launching not a valid subject? I could write It results in Peter is launching that Amy is laughing. In that case, it refers to Amy is laughing

@Shuzeng:  Your sentence is ungrammatical, truly a garbled mess. Peter is laughing is not a valid object of preposition in in the phrasal verb "result in". That verb wants a nominal constituent as complement.

@Shuzheng Awkward but grammatical:  "That Amy is laughing results in Peter frowning." or "It results in Peter frowning that Amy is laughing."

NOTE:  "that Amy is laughing" is not the same as "Amy is laughing".
